# Javascript Textbox Value

Tags: javascript

I have a colour picker:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="msg" name="msg" value="msg">
<label for="background-color">Choose a calor for background : </label>
<input id="background-color" type="color" value="#ff0000" onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('chosen-color').value = document.getElementById('background-color').value;"/>



<label for="chosen-color">You have chosen : </label>
<input id="chosen-color" type="text" value="#ff0000"/>
```

The Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('msg').addEventListener('click', function() {
          alert (colorPicker);
          }, false);

    //Color Picker    
    var colorPicker = (document.getElementById('chosen-color').value);
```

The message box just shows the default value FF0000 when I click the button for message box, even though it shows a different value. How do I make it show the actual value?

Comment: Why is this tagged as jQuery when you are using pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never actually updating the `colorPicker` value.

```
document.getElementById('msg').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert (document.getElementById('chosen-color').value);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('msg').addEventListener('click', function() {
          alert (colorPicker.value);
          }, false);

    //Color Picker    
    var colorPicker = (document.getElementById('chosen-color'));
```

The problem was that you were not updating the value of colorpicker after it changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `colorPicker` doesn't get updated. You should also consider not using `onchange=""` and bringing that into the javascript with another event listener.

```
var colorPicker = document.getElementById('chosen-color');

document.getElementById('msg').addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert (colorPicker.value);
        }, false);

document.getElementById('background-color').addEventListener('change', function() {
            colorPicker.value = this.value;
        }, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

document.getElementById('#msg').addEventListener('click', function() {
          alert (colorPicker);
          }, false);

```
//Color Picker    
var colorPicker = (document.getElementById('#chosen-color').value);
```

Comment: `getElementById` does not use CSS selector syntax. -1